# AngularJS: setting the previously selected option in the tag <select>

Tags: angularjs

In the form I have a drop down list with multiple choice, as shown below. Elements are loaded from the database.

```
<label>Items</label>

<select class="form-control m-b" 
        ng-model="model.livingComplexId" 
        x-ng-change="updateOne(model.livingComplexId)">

    <option></option>
    <option ng-repeat="itemOne in itemsForAddrLevelOne" 
            value="{{itemOne.id}}">{{itemOne.tobName}}</option>
</select>
```

[image]

I make choose.

[image]

For example, I choose an `item2`.

Then save data. Then, I open the form to edit and I want to see an item that I chose, but the list is empty...

[image]

How can I set the previously selected value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use the [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive to generate the select menu options:

```
 <select ng-model="model.livingComplexId" ng-options="itemOne.id as itemOne.tobName for itemOne in itemsForAddrLevelOne"></select>
```

Maybe you could additionally change the ng-model value to `model` and use `ng-options="itemOne as ..."` (without the `.id`) and add an `track by itemOne.id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="yourModel" ng-options="itemOne.tobName for itemOne in itemsForAddrLevelOne"></select>
```

In the js you should set `$scope.yourModel = itemsForAddrLevelOne[0];`